# AttributeError: module 'resource' has no attribute 'getpagesize'

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, object-detection

I am trying to use Tensorflow Object Detection API and I follow the steps mentioned in the given link -

https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#tf-models-install

When I try to access the Object Detection Jupyter Notebook through `jupyter notebook`

I am facing the below exception

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 7, in <module>
    from notebook.notebookapp import main
  File "/home/dinesh/.local/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 79, in <module>
    from .base.handlers import Template404, RedirectWithParams
  File "/home/dinesh/.local/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/notebook/base/handlers.py", line 32, in <module>
    import prometheus_client
  File "/home/dinesh/.local/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/prometheus_client/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from . import process_collector
  File "/home/dinesh/.local/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/prometheus_client/process_collector.py", line 12, in <module>
_PAGESIZE = resource.getpagesize()
AttributeError: module 'resource' has no attribute 'getpagesize'
```

I am using

```
Python - 3.6.3

Jupyter - 1.0.0
```

How can I overcome this exception?

Answer (score 2):

Got a similar error. My project contained modules (folders)

- model
- resource  (replaced with resources)
- service

So I changed the name of the resource module to resources (change name to any appropriate module name)

Answer (score 1):

I have the same error ,after rename my `resource` module in the `PYTHONPATH` , it works right. check your PYTHONPATH, is there a resource module?

Answer (score 1):

[Quick look for root cause]
Check if you have set PYTHONPATH in your system -

1. try to rename that momentarily
2. run "jupyter notebook"

[Fix the issue]
if the issue is resolved by doing this then

1. search "resource" folder within all paths mentioned in PYTHONPATH
2. if such folder found then rename/refactor it to other name e.g. "resources"

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error as you did,and upon investigation, I discovered that I had mistakenly created a resource folder in the root directory of the running application.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was mamba installed graalvm's python for some reason, and that version of python does not have `resource.getpagesize`. Using conda and their version of python solves the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I realized I was on Python 3.8.5, which I think doesn't have that function. I updated to 3.8.17 and that fixed the issue.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue on starting Jupyter Notebooks on Windows 10.
When I initially ran the regular startup script, I got a windows terminal that opened and immediately closed, too fast to see any error messages.  So, I opened a windows 10 powershell terminal and ran

> conda update conda
> and
> conda update --all
> then I ran
> jupyter-notebook at the windows prompt.  The results were:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "E:\Users\Bob\anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 6, in 
from notebook.notebookapp import main
File "E:\Users\Bob\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 76, in 
from .base.handlers import Template404, RedirectWithParams
File "E:\Users\Bob\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\base\handlers.py", line 24, in 
import prometheus_client
File "E:\Users\Bob\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\prometheus_client_*init*_.py", line 3, in 
from . import (
File "E:\Users\Bob\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\prometheus_client\process_collector.py", line 11, in 
_PAGESIZE = resource.getpagesize()
AttributeError: module 'resource' has no attribute 'getpagesize'

I opened process_collector.py in the site-packages\prometheus_client in notepad++ and changed
line 9 import resource to import resources
and
line 11 _PAGESIZE = resource.getpagesize() to _PAGESIZE = resources.getpagesize()

I searched for other instances of resource and found none. I then saved the file and reran jupyter-notebook at the windows terminal prompt.

This time I got:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "E:\Users\Bob\anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 10, in 
sys.exit(main())
File "E:\Users\Bob\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\application.py", line 254, in launch_instance
return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
File "E:\Users\Bob\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 844, in launch_instance
app.initialize(argv)
File "E:\Users\Bob\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 87, in inner
return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
File "E:\Users\Bob\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 2126, in initialize
self.init_resources()
File "E:\Users\Bob\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 1697, in init_resources
old_soft, old_hard = resource.getrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_NOFILE)
AttributeError: module 'resource' has no attribute 'getrlimit'

Still having Notepad++ open, I opened notebookapp.py in site-packages\notebook and searched for resource.  I found and changed the following lines:
Line 37     import resource to import resources
line 40     resource = None to resources = None
line 1036   resource is None to resources is None
line 1040   soft, hard = resource.getrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_NOFILE) to
soft, hard = resources.getrlimit(resources.RLIMIT_NOFILE)
line 1693  if resource is None: to if resources is None:
line 1697  old_soft, old_hard = resource.getrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_NOFILE) to        old_soft, old_hard = resources.getrlimit(resources.RLIMIT_NOFILE)
line 1706  resource.setrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_NOFILE, (soft, hard)) to
resources.setrlimit(resources.RLIMIT_NOFILE, (soft, hard))

I searched for other instances of resource and found none. I then saved the notebookapp.py file and reran jupyter-notebook at the windows terminal prompt.  This time Jupyter Notebooks opened with the expected files tab displayed.  I quit out of Jupyter Notebooks and restarted using the normal link to the startup script and it worked as expected.

I am not sure what caused this issue.  I did not intentionally update anything before I saw the issue.  Yesterday, Jupyter Notebooks worked as expected, today when I tried to run it, I got the flicker screen as described above.

Comment: please add some code formatting with ``` surrounds, to make it easier to read.